# intellij create project from existing sources vs. from external model

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

When choosing file => new project from existing sources I am not understanding the difference between  "create project from existing sources" and "create project from external model".
[image]

I thought with the option "from existing sources" intellij is able to detect the build tool that is being used and build the project just like it does when I select "from external model" and select "gradle". But somehow that is not the same. I have a grade + kotlin + springBoot project and when I select "create from existing sources" intellij builds the project with gradle and it is also able to run it but some springboot dependencies are not resolved, something with the gradle configuration is messed up. Could not figure out what exactly. When I choose "create project from external model" everything just runs out of the box.

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#import-project to learn about the differences between these imports.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you have the time I have 2 follow-up questions: "Use this type of import to create an IntelliJ IDEA project over the existing source code that is <not necessarily> an exported project." With "not an exported project" I guess they mean just a simple application that does not involve a build tool like maven or gradle and that has not been exported by eclipse or intellij, is that right? "not necessarily" but that means it could or could not be. So technically I still don't get why I am not able to import the gradle project correctly with this option.